# Bootstrap.sh file is not available after appium installation in mac

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, ios-ui-automation

Trying to run automation scripts in an iOS App. After installing Appium the Bootstrap.sh file is not available in the location. Whenever I'm running the script from Eclipse in Mac OS I'm getting Test Build failed. And "Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65" Am I doing something incorrectly?
Here is the list of item that are already installed.

1. Eclipse
2. Xcode
3. Appium
4. Appium Doctor
5. Carthage
6. Homebrew

Comment: did you find any solution dude?

Comment: Actually, the issue was in Xcode. While building the WebDriverAgent project agent the error code 65 was being thrown due to apple sign in credentials. Check for the correct Bundle Identifier for each project in project properties. That should solve the issue.